# What kinds of statements are induction-friendly?

Tags: logic, soft-question, induction

When I say that that the statement is *induction-friendly* I mean that it is possible to prove that statement by not using any other known method of proof except mathematical induction.

For example, we can prove by the method of mathematical induction that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k= \dfrac {n(n+1)}{2}$ but I seriously doubt that we can prove with mathematical induction only that every $n$-th degree complex polynomial has exactly $n$ complex roots.

So, my question would be:

> Is there some characterization of statements that are *induction-friendly*?

Comment: I think there's nothing that complicated to talk about here: induction-friendly statements are those where there is a clear inductive step taking you from one hypothesis to the next. However, these may not be easy to see: there is quite a famous proof of the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality (attributed to Cauchy) where it is shown that $P(n) \implies P(2n)$ and $P(n) \implies P(n - 1)$.

Comment: "not using any other known method of proof" -- how do you plan to prove the base case and induction step, then?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no method, no formula, no characterization, for this. It is generally impossible to determine ahead of time whether "it is possible to prove" a statement using a particular technique, unless you actually try that technique. Maybe you succeed, then great, the proof technique works. Maybe you fail, then bummer, the proof technique doesn't work... or... maybe you just didn't go about it correctly.

Comment: And if you do accept other proof techiques within the induction step: Once you have proved (by appropriate means) that every nonconstant complex polynomial has _at least_ one complex root, what you need to get from there to "exactly $n$ roots" is precisely ... induction on the degree!

Comment: Perhaps a necessary condition for induction-friendliness would be that the statement involves the natural numbers.

Comment: @Lee Mosher I agree, but would say 'so far no method....' and probably add 'and I doubt there will ever be one.' Or is it provable there is 'no method, no formula, no characterization, for this.'?

Comment: @Joel Reyes Noche  Is this true? I can't help but wonder if induction has been extended to other ordered sets.

Comment: @Arby It is a theorem that no algorithm exists which inputs an arbitrary mathematical statement and outputs a proof or a disproof.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche That seems way too restrictive. Any well-ordered (or just well-founded) set will do. So in some sense, any set and it is up to us to find the "good" way to order it.

Comment: @Arby Induction works in much greater generality than on the natural numbers. I wrote a blog post about this some time ago here, but the blog is gone now and I have no idea if it is easily findable.

Comment: It seems like you are defining 'induction-friendly' as that it *must* use induction, but that seems like a high bar to meet; In fact, your very example that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k= \dfrac {n(n+1)}{2}$ can be proven in ways that don't involve induction. Think of Gauss' famous method to do this. So maybe you just want to say that 'induction would be very helpful  to prove it'?